# Linux joystick seems mis-calibrated in an SDL game (Freespace 2 Open)

Tags: linux, game-controller, sdl

I have a USB joystick (Saitek Cyborg 3D) which shows up on my recently installed Ubuntu 9.04 box as `/dev/input/js0`, and `jstest` is showing values in the range +-32767 as I would expect. I just dug up a copy of [FreeSpace Open](http://scp.indiegames.us/), a game which uses SDL and worked with no problems on a previous Ubuntu install about a year ago, and the joystick seems very mis-calibrated. All axes (X, Y, twist, throttle) seem at least 20% off-center. The X and Y axes at least definitely aren't reaching their end points.

A [relevant message](http://www.nabble.com/SDL-joystick-ranges-have-change-%28Ubuntu%29-td21631811.html#a21631811) on the SDL mailing list in January 2009 received no concrete answers.

Here is [joy-unix.cpp](http://svn.icculus.org/fs2open/trunk/fs2_open/code/io/joy-unix.cpp?view=markup) from the project source. I'm not quite running trunk, but as you can see from the revision log there, no actual code changes have happened to that file for over 3 years.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I noticed the problem in [d2x](http://icculus.org/d2x/) (a Descent port), which also uses SDL, so I went digging in SDL. `testjoystick` from the SDL source showed the problem as well. Looking at the [SDL linux joystick driver](http://www.libsdl.org/cgi/viewvc.cgi/branches/SDL-1.2/src/joystick/linux/SDL_sysjoystick.c?view=markup), the problem is mentioned. Search for `joydev_pattern` in that file and you'll see what they're doing; search for `calibrate` and they do mention this problem. Basically they use `/dev/input/event6` (or whichever) in preference to `/dev/input/js0`, unless compiled with `--disable-input-events`, even knowing the event device can't be calibrated (i.e. the calibration set on `js0` will be ignored).

Having found all that, Google searches involving that `configure` option reveal that hidden away in the comments to a Linux howto for `fs2_open`, [someone has actually had this problem already](http://www.hard-light.net/forums/index.php?topic=17364.msg572070#msg572070).

I have [reported this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libsdl1.2/+bug/410187) to Ubuntu. To work around, pick any one of:

- Set `SDL_JOYSTICK_DEVICE=/dev/input/js0` (you could put this in `/etc/environment` and reboot to apply it everywhere). **Edit:** SDL will still have the `evdev` device as a second joystick, so in games like `d2x` that respond to the second joystick as well by default, visit the options screen and remove those extra bindings.
- Recompile libSDL with `--disable-input-events`.
- `rmmod evdev` (quite likely to lose any unusual input devices you have).

Comment: Exact same problem, exact same joystick.  your first option worked beautifully.  saved me hours of frustration.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the game needs to be provided with the min/max/center axis values from the joystick. The default values might be 0/32768/65536 rather than -32676/0/32760 you're seeing? That's more obviously a lot more than 20% off, so maybe it's trying to auto-calibrate at some point. It also looks like the `joytest2` console command can show in-game values which might provide some added insight.

From `joy_init()`:

```
// Fake a calibration
if (joy_num_sticks > 0) {
    for (i=0; i<JOY_NUM_AXES; i++) {
        joystick.axis_center[i] = 32768;
        joystick.axis_min[i] = 0;
        joystick.axis_max[i] = 65536;
    }
}
```

I see a calibration function (`joy_cheap_cal()` at `joy.cpp:454`) but it's not immediately obvious where that's called from, or if there are other methods within the game for re-calibrating the axis values. I love Freespace, so when I get home I'll download the code and poke around a bit. You might also try running `jscal` just for good measure?